# error with mainactivity.java

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R cannot be resolved to a variable - Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498869/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-hello-world)

I was developing my first app but get stuck on `mainactivity.java`.

Here is my code:

```
package com.nterface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
    }

}
```

An error occurs on line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Multiple markers at this line:

- R cannot be resolved to a variable
- Line breakpoint:MainActivity [line: 12]- 
  onCreate(Bundle)

Comment: Clean the project (Project -> Clean)

Comment: put your activity_main.xml file.

Comment: Generate the R file by clean your project from Project => Clean.

Comment: Search for the same question. there are many similar questions already exists in the StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

First Clean your project and then run.If not effected then Once restart your eclipse and clean the project and Run it.
If not then go through the following [link](http://www.mybringback.com/travis-android-help/1/hello-world/).

Answer (score 0):

You should import your `R.java`, it should be in `com.nterface.R`

Comment: R.java would be auto imported if it is in the same package.